# UWP App Dynamic Pivot MVVM always creating new instance of viewmodel

Tags: xaml, mvvm, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I need help with my code. I'm trying to achieve a layout like in the image below
[image]

So far I have created an UWP Windows 10 app and it looks like this below 
[image: my app]

I'm using Vb.net but C# is welcomed as well. Trying to follow Mvvm pattern and also using no extra mvvm framework - just xaml behaviours.

My End goal is to be able to double click a page and then create a new tab with the header bind to the page name . For test purposes I added an add page and add tab button because the double click isn't working correctly. Every time a new item is added to the collection for the tabs, it isn't reflected in the ui because the data template is creating a new instance of my viewmodel which is what I don't want to happen. The temporary add buttons calls the correct methods and does the functionality I want to achieve with the double click. Ill post the shortest example of my code below.

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                        <Button  Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Add Page" Foreground="White">
                        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                                <Core:CallMethodAction MethodName="AddPage" TargetObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </Button>
                        <Button  Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Add Tab" Foreground="White">
                            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                                    <Core:CallMethodAction MethodName="AddSection" TargetObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Pivot Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Foreground="White" ItemsSource="{Binding PivotItems, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                        <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="White"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                        <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Result, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                                    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="DoubleTapped">
                                            <Core:CallMethodAction MethodName="AddSection"/>
                                        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid x:Name="CanvasControl" Background="#00000000" Width="200" Height="200" >
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="11*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                <Canvas Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" Background="White" DoubleTapped="Canvas_DoubleTapped" />


                                                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"  Foreground="White" FontSize="14" TextAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="0" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Text="{Binding CanvasCollection[0].CanvasName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  Foreground="White" FontSize="12"  TextAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="10" IsHitTestVisible="False" Text="{Binding CanvasCollection[0].CanvasMaster}" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>

                                </GridView>

                            </DataTemplate>


                        </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                    </Pivot>
                </Grid>
```

Viewmodel

```
Public Class ProjectDataViewModel

Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Private WindowData As New CanvasData
Private randomdata As New DataGenerators
Private m_PivotItems As New ObservableCollection(Of PivotSection)
Private Canvas_Collection As New ObservableCollection(Of CanvasData)
Private mycollection As New CanvasData
Private pivotItem_Home As New PivotSection() With {.Name = "Home"}

Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(Optional propertyName As String = "")
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Public Property PropertyCollectionItemName As String
    Get
        Return WindowData.CanvasName
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        WindowData.CanvasName = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property PropertyCollectionItemMaster As String
    Get
        Return WindowData.CanvasMaster
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        WindowData.CanvasMaster = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property CanvasCollection As ObservableCollection(Of CanvasData)
    Get
        Return Canvas_Collection
    End Get
    Private Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of CanvasData))
        Canvas_Collection = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property

Public Property my_collection As CanvasData
    Get
        Return mycollection
    End Get
    Set(value As CanvasData)
        mycollection = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property

Public Property PivotItems() As ObservableCollection(Of PivotSection)
    Get
        Return m_PivotItems
    End Get
    Set
        m_PivotItems = Value
        NotifyPropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property


Public Sub AddSection()

    Dim pivotItem_New As New PivotSection() With {.Name = "Item Header " + PivotItems.Count.ToString}
    m_PivotItems.Add(pivotItem_New)


End Sub
Public Sub AddPage()
    Dim Newpage As New PivotItemContent
    Newpage.CanvasCollection.Add(New CanvasData With {.CanvasName = "Page " + pivotItem_Home.Result.Count.ToString, .CanvasMaster = "Master "})
    pivotItem_Home.Result.Add(newpage)
End Sub


Sub New()
    Dim indexPage As New PivotItemContent
    PivotItems = New ObservableCollection(Of PivotSection)
    PivotItems.Add(pivotItem_Home)
    indexPage.CanvasCollection.Add(New CanvasData With {.CanvasName = "Home", .CanvasMaster = "Master"})

    pivotItem_Home.Result.Add(indexPage)

End Sub
```

PivotSection Class

```
End Class

Public Class PivotSection
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(Optional propertyName As String = "")
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return m_Name
    End Get
    Set
        m_Name = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Name As String
Public Property SystemLabel() As String
    Get
        Return m_SystemLabel
    End Get
    Set
        m_SystemLabel = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_SystemLabel As String
Public Property Result() As ObservableCollection(Of PivotItemContent)
    Get
        Return m_Result
    End Get
    Set
        m_Result = Value
        NotifyPropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Result As New ObservableCollection(Of PivotItemContent)

'Public Sub New()
'    Result = New ObservableCollection(Of PivotGroup)
'End Sub
End Class
```

PivotContent Class

```
Public Class PivotItemContent
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(Optional propertyName As String = "")
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
Private Canvas_Collection As New ObservableCollection(Of CanvasData)
Public Property CanvasCollection As ObservableCollection(Of CanvasData)
    Get
        Return Canvas_Collection
    End Get
    Private Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of CanvasData))
        Canvas_Collection = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property

Private Page_Name As String
Public Property PageName As String
    Get
        Return Page_Name
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Page_Name = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property

Private Page_Master As String
Public Property PageMaster As String
    Get
        Return Page_Master
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Page_Master = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

CavasDataclass

```
Imports Windows.UI

Public Class CanvasData
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged


Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(Optional propertyName As String = "")
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub


Private _CanvasMaster_Name As String
Private _CanvasName As String




Public Property CanvasMaster() As String
    Get
        Return _CanvasMaster_Name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _CanvasMaster_Name = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property


Public Property CanvasName As String
    Get
        Return _CanvasName
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _CanvasName = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can have a `TabList` page, that will contain the `GridView` with all the opened tabs. Each item will use a `ItemTemplate` in which you can add a close button and a preview.

To enable opening a tab, you can set the `GridView`'s `IsItemClickEnabled` property to `true` and then handle the `ItemClick` event to know which tab was clicked by the user. You can then use this information to navigate to a `TabDetail`  page, which you create.

Creating new tab will be also simple - just adding a new item into the `GridView` and navigating to it directly.